# Make Spinner Text Align Properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am trying to Make `SearchableSpinner` Text Alignment Proper

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
                android:id="@+id/statespinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                app:hintText="Please Select your State"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                />
            <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
                android:id="@+id/districtspinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                app:hintText="Please Select your District"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />
            <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
                android:id="@+id/assemblyspinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                app:hintText="Please Select your Assembly Constituency"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                />
            <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
                android:id="@+id/wardspinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                app:hintText="Please Select your Ward"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
               />
</LinearLayout>
```

Result of Recent Code :

[image: Result]

As you can see when I select any state it go to Left side of Spinner. I want to to make similar aligned with non selected Fields.

Comment: If you are using custom layout then you have to apply same padding to textview as you did for spinner

Comment: can you provide any example sir ?

Comment: Just remove `android:padding="4dp"` it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a TextView in a custom layout for showing the dropdown item in the spinner, then you must put some padding to that TextView.

Something like:

spinner_item.xml

(Padding whichever applicable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="25dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:background="#b3e2ff"
/>
```

Or

(Padding on all sides)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="4dp" />
```

Let me know if you need more help.